# Python: convert pdf to csv (multi-line column)

Tags: python, csv, pdf, multiline, tabula

My CSV is:

```
,Élément,État général,Observations
0,ENTRÉE,Etat d'usage,
1,PORTES,Etat d'usage,Chaînette cassé
Serrure du bas en mauvais état le système est
cassé au niveau de la chaînette
2,ENTRÉE / PORTESENTRÉE / PORTES,,
3,Type de porte,,Porte blindée
4,Poignée,,Bon état
5,Couleur,,Bois
```

But i want this:

```
,Élément,État général,Observations
0,ENTRÉE,Etat d'usage,
1,PORTES,Etat d'usage,Chaînette cassé; Serrure du bas en mauvais état le système ...
2,ENTRÉE / PORTESENTRÉE / PORTES,,
3,Type de porte,,Porte blindée
4,Poignée,,Bon état
5,Couleur,,Bois
```

My code simply converts one or more pdf to a csv for each page and looks like this:

```
import os
import io
import shutil
import tabula
import time

start_time = time.time()
path = './'

i=0
j=0

for( directory, subdirectories, file ) in os.walk(path):
    for f in file:
        if f.endswith('.pdf'):
                df = tabula.read_pdf(str(directory) + "/" + str(f), pages='all')
                i=0
                j+=1
                for curr_df in df:
                    i+=1
                    curr_df.to_csv('./' + str(directory) + '-' + str(i) + '.csv')

print("--- convert %d .PDF to %d .CSV in %s seconds ---" % (j, i, time.time() - start_time))
```

My problem is also due to the fact that I can't do case by case. I need to be able to process all csv in the same way

Comment: I cannot understand how pandas `to_csv` could generate an incorrect csv file. Multi line fields are common in CSV files, but they should have been included in quotes. Can Pandas correctly read those file with `pd.read_csv`? Currently it looks like a bug in Pandas which is weird...

Comment: Hello @SergeBallesta I didn't use panda but tabula do you think it's a mistake on my part?

Comment: tabula `read_pdf` normally returns a list of Pandas DataFrames. And `to_csv` is a method of pandas `DataFrame`, which normally produces a well behaving file. To type to load a csv file with pandas, you could use `import pandas as pd` `df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')` `print(df.info())` `print(df)` and report what you get.

Comment: I get an error, I show it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open the `csv`, read the lines, and add the strings that do not start empty (header) or with a number to the previous line. Then write the lines to a new `csv` file:

```
with open('filename.csv') as f:
    text = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()] #remove newline character with rstrip()
    lines = []
    for i in text:
        try:
            if i[0] ==',' or i[0].isnumeric():
                lines.append(i)
            else:
                lines[-1] = lines[-1] + "; " + i
        except:
            continue
            
with open('new_file.csv', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as newfile:
    newfile.write('\n'.join(lines)) # reinsert newline characters with '\n'.join()
```

To process all files in a directory we can put it in a function and feed all files in a directory to that function:

```
import os as os
import glob as glob

def process_csv(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        text = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()] #remove newline character with rstrip()
        lines = []
        for i in text:
            try:
                if i[0] ==',' or i[0].isnumeric():
                    lines.append(i)
                else:
                    lines[-1] = lines[-1] + "; " + i
            except:
                continue

    with open(os.path.basename(filepath) + '_fixed.csv', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as newfile:
        newfile.write('\n'.join(lines)) # reinsert newline characters with '\n'.join()
        print('fixed: ' + os.path.basename(filepath) + '_fixed.csv')

files = glob.glob('./*.csv') #use glob to create a list of filepath of csv files in a directory

for file in files: # loop through the list and feed each file to the function process_csv
    process_csv(file)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Do you have a solution to process several files. 
ex: 
with open (./CSV/*.csv) and save them in a folder.
Sorry, I'm new to python.

Comment: Moreover I have just realized that it creates a new column whereas I would like "Chaînette cassé; Serrure du bas en mauvais état le système ..." to be in the same column. @RJAdriaansen

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer to show how you can process an entire directory at once. It does not create a new column by the way. It links the sentence parts with `;` as indicated in your desired output. But the columns are separated with `,`. See for yourself by loading the file in `pandas` with `pd.read_csv('filename.csv')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RJAdriaansen it helps me a lot.
However I still have a problem with some of my .csv I post the error above

Comment: Ok, I have inserted a `try-except` in the answer that will manage the empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

For @SergeBallesta this is what I have:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8 entries, 0 to 7
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------        --------------  ----- 
 0   Unnamed: 0    8 non-null      object
 1   Élément       6 non-null      object
 2   État général  2 non-null      object
 3   Observations  4 non-null      object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 384.0+ bytes
None
                                      Unnamed: 0                         Élément  État général     Observations
0                                              0                          ENTRÉE  Etat d'usage              NaN
1                                              1                          PORTES  Etat d'usage  Chaînette cassé
2  Serrure du bas en mauvais état le système est                             NaN           NaN              NaN
3                cassé au niveau de la chaînette                             NaN           NaN              NaN
4                                              2  ENTRÉE / PORTESENTRÉE / PORTES           NaN              NaN
5                                              3                   Type de porte           NaN    Porte blindée
6                                              4                         Poignée           NaN         Bon état
7                                              5                         Couleur           NaN             Bois
```

with

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('../CSV/Entire/PDF-1.csv') 
print(df.info()) 
print(df)
```

Comment: This tries to load a **PDF** file using Pandas read_csv. What I meant was to load a **CSV** file produced by `...to_csv(...)`

Comment: Sorry, I feel so stupid... I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For @RJAdriaansen this is the error I get:

```
fixed: PDF-8.csv_fixed.csv
fixed: PDF-5.csv_fixed.csv
fixed: PDF-7.csv_fixed.csv
fixed: PDF-6.csv_fixed.csv
fixed: PDF-2.csv_fixed.csv
fixed: PDF-10.csv_fixed.csv
fixed: PDF-3.csv_fixed.csv
fixed: PDF-4.csv_fixed.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "corrCSV_v2.py", line 24, in <module>
    process_csv(file)
  File "corrCSV_v2.py", line 12, in process_csv
    if i[0] ==',' or i[0].isnumeric():
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The error comes from this .csv

```
,Élément,État général,Observations
0,CUISINE,Etat d'usage,
1,CUISINECUISINE 15CUISINE 18

CUISINE 19,,
```

I think it's due to the empty line